# How to do I expand this conditional, joint probability?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, joint-distribution

Is $\Pr(y \ , \mu |, H_0)$ equal to $\Pr(y \ | \mu)\Pr(\mu | H_0)$ or $\Pr(y \ | \mu , H_0)\Pr(\mu | H_0)$?

Comment: The second because you have to have the condition $|H_0$ in both probabilities, unless of course some simplification can be done.

Comment: @JohnK, why not put that as an official answer (perhaps w/ a little elaboration)?

Comment: Keep in mind probabilities are not the same as densities. Some of your notation is suggesting the use of one, while other parts are suggesting the use of the other. If we're talking about densities the accepted answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the second expansion that is the correct one because you need to keep the condition on $H_0$ on both probabilities. Once you have done that, you are allowed to treat the conditional probabilities as regular probabilities and all rules you know apply.

Having said that, often a simplifcation of

$$\Pr \left(A, B | C \right) = \Pr \left(A |B, C \right) \Pr \left(B |C \right) $$

is possible. If, say, you know that the events $A$ and $C$ are conditionally indendent (given $B$), then the first term on the RHS becomes simply $\Pr \left(A |B \right)$.

You will find these rules particularly useful in Bayesian statistics.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely the second one. Maybe the first one.

It's definitely the second one because $Pr(y|\mu,H_0) Pr(\mu|H_0) = \frac{Pr(y,\mu,H_0)}{Pr(\mu,H_0)} \frac{Pr(\mu,H_0)}{Pr(H_0)} = Pr(y,\mu|H_0)$.

It's the first one if we assume that $y$ is independent of $H_0$ given $\mu$, which gives us $Pr(y|\mu,H_0) = Pr(y|\mu)$.